# Confusion: $q(x) = \begin{cases} (\sin(x))^2 \cdot |\sin(\frac{1}{x})| & \text{for } x \ne 0, \\ 0 & \text{for } x = 0 \end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I came across the following problem, which I struggle to solve:

1. Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, such that $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, it fulfills $0 \leq f(x) \leq x^2$. Does it follow from these assumptions that $f$ has in point $ x = 0 $ derivation? Does it follow from these assumptions that $ f'(0)= 0$?
2. Let's define the function $ q: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
   $q(x) = \begin{cases}
         (\sin(x))^2 \cdot |\sin(\frac{1}{x})| & \text{for } x \ne 0, \\
         0 & \text{for } x = 0
      \end{cases}$

Does the $q$ have derivation in 0, and if so, what does it equal to?

Any ideas as I really struggle with solving this? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What has the title to do with the question ?

Comment: Please ask one problem at a time.  Your terse posting gives me the impression that you are simply passing through two problems without any effort to research or relate them.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

for 1. show that

$$ \\|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}| \le |x|$$

for all $x \ne 0.$  Conclusion ?

for 2. show that

$$ \\|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}| \le 2| \sin x|$$

for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $0$, $x \ne 0.$